# RDP-ing or RDC-ing

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp, terminal-server, rdc

I have always used the terminology RDP-ing when describing connecting to a remote desktop. Today I heard a colleague use the term RDC-ing, which triggered a debate.

I have not been able to find any publications that can help steer the debate. Does anybody know what the correct terminology is, preferably with supporting citations?

Comment: Six of one and a half dozen of the other.

Comment: @joeqwerty bakers dozen?

Answer (score 6):

Neither is 'Correct' per-say, but RDP-ing, is less incorrect.

*FTP-ing*, *SCP-ing*, The Protocol is used in slang more frequently and if you wanted to be consistent I would stick with that.

And if you consult the oracle

[image: RDCing]
[image: RDPing]

Answer (score 1):

I have always used RDP-ing.  I just left a place, where a co-worker referred to it as RDC...and I found it odd.

Comment: Good reason to leave!

Comment: Yeah, he was handed everything, did nothing, and blamed everyone else for his failure.  Glad to be out of that place.